# Using Python selenium to click button inside the table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to extract the data from the website, here:

https://apps.ecology.wa.gov/tcpwebreporting/reports/ust?CityZip=Seattle&County=King&StoredSubstance=Unleaded%20Gasoline

I click the `>` button to get more details of each gas station. I was trying to scrape the data, but I couldn't find a way to click `>` button using my codes.

I am able to extract each row's elements. what should I do next?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Career\Coltura\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://apps.ecology.wa.gov/tcpwebreporting/reports/ust?CityZip=Seattle&County=King&StoredSubstance=Unleaded%20Gasoline')
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(' details-control parent-td clickable parent-control')
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
```

```
<tr class="clickable odd details" role="row">
    <td class=" details-control parent-td clickable parent-control">
        <button title="Toggle more information about the site RICK'S CHEVRON GROCERY" class="btn btn-sm btn-whitesmoke"></button>
    </td>
    <td class=" parent-td">27</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">41179492</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">A3602</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">RICK'S CHEVRON GROCERY</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">8506 5TH AVE NE</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">Seattle</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">98115</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">King</td>
    <td class=" parent-td">Northwest</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate element with multiple class name, you can use `*_by_css_selector` not `_by_class_name`.

I suggest to use method : `.location_once_scrolled_into_view` before click the element.

This is for click each arrow button you mean:

```
driver.get('https://apps.ecology.wa.gov/tcpwebreporting/reports/ust?CityZip=Seattle&County=King&StoredSubstance=Unleaded%20Gasoline')

#add some wait here.....

arrows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td[class*="details-control"]')
for arrow in arrows:
    arrow.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    time.sleep(0.5)
    arrow.click()
```